# How to find all the peaks in a given 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I want to find all the peak points of a given 1D array which was generated like this:
`vertical_projection = np.sum(projCopy, axis=0)`(This array contains the sum of black pixels in each column of a binary image.)
when I print this array I get,

```
    [1213 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335 1335
     960    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0  957  958  958  958  959  960  974 1072 1073
     1072 1007 1008 1007  998  998  997  996  996  996  995  907  741  706
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  755 1331 1332]
```

so I want to print all the array indexes of the peak points without providing any threshold value to calculate the peak points.

Comment: what would your expected output be for that array?

Comment: @DanielF It should be the array indexes of values 1335(from 1st group of non zero values), 1073 (from second group of non zero values), 1332(from last group which is 755,1331,1332)

Comment: You mention nonzero values. Do you mean that you consider only one "peak" per stretch of nonzero values ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes

Comment: In case of ties, what should you return ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust array indexes of maximum value of  each nonzero value group

Comment: Do yo mean all indexes ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust in the first group 1335 is in multiple indexes..so in that case it is better if I can get the index of the mid point from the indexes which contain 1335

Comment: What if there are three distant places where the same maximum is reached ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust then I want all three indexes

Comment: So now your question is much more elaborate than "find all the peak points". It would probably be useful to disclose the use of this, to check if your definition makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delimit the slices where the array is nonzero.
2. In every slice, find the maximum.
3. In every slice, delimit the subslices where that maximum is achieved.
4. Now return the middle of every subslice.

1 and 2 can be made during a single pass over the array, and 3 and 4 require a second local pass in every slice.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with the `numpy.argwhere` and then `numpy.flatten` to receive the desired outcome, as shown in the following example:

```
import numpy as np

rr = np.array([1213, 1335, 1335, 1335, 1335, 1335, 1335, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1008, 1007, 998, 998, 997, 996, 996, 996])
th = 1200
np.argwhere(arr==arr.max()).flatten()
```

**Output:**

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Cheers.

Comment: I'm looking for a method that I don't have to provide any threshold value. btw thanks for the answer

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer for this purpose. Cheers.